# Ascii Conversion Error

Tags: c

This program compiles correctly, but when i put a number between 32 and 127 (The correct range) it completes the loop. Can anyone tell me a way i could write it where in the first while loop if i input i (32-128) it continues, and input j between ((i+1)-128)?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 64

int main(){

    char line[LEN];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    while(i<32 | i>128) {
        printf("Enter a #, 32-127: ");
        fgets(line,LEN,stdin);
        int i = atoi(line);
}
    while(j<=i | j>128) {
        printf("Enter a second  #, %d-127: ",i);
        fgets(line,LEN,stdin);
        int j = atoi(line);
}
    while(i<=j) {
       printf("ASCII value of character %d: %c\n",i,i);
       i++;
}

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Please please please use fscanf instead of fgets and atoi!

Comment: And if you want to check input, please check it *after* you get the input, not before.

Comment: Don't use bitwise operators.

Comment: Also, you're assigning your atoi result into block local variables instead of function level. Remove the 'int' at the start of your atoi statements.

Comment: '|' means bitwise OR. You want `||`, logical OR.

Comment: I have changed the logical or, but still yields the same response.

Comment: Your `int i` inside the loop is local inside the loop. Not the same `i` as you are testing in the `while` statement.

Comment: Even aside from using the wrong operator, your condition is wrong. You want to ignore numbers less than 32 or greater than 127, so why have >128? And then you print i-127, but you don't want i. Programming requires care and precision.

Comment: Recommend `while(i<32 | i>127)`, not `while(i<32 | i>128)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove 'int' from the lines

```
int i= atoi(line);
```

and

```
int j= atoi(line);
```

Just write them as:

```
i= atoi(line);
```

and

```
j= atoi(line);
```

then see if it works. Your version re-declares these variables again inside the loop body and their values are lost when the while loop reaches the test. Also, the proper 'logical or' operator is '||' not '|'.

Answer (score 0):

See comments for explanation of my changes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//  not needed if you don't use a buffer
//#define LEN 64 

int main(){
    // buffer not needed with fscanf
    //char line[LEN];  
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(i < 32 || i > 128) { // use logical '||' not bitwise '|'
        printf("Enter a #, 32-127: ");
        fscanf(stdin, "%i", &i); // use fscanf instead of fgets, buffer and atoi

        //fgets(line,LEN,stdin);
        // you were assigning to a variable local to loop here which
        // goes out of scope at end of loop
        //int i = atoi(line);
    }

    while(j <= i | j > 128) {
        printf("Enter a second  #, %d-127: ",i);
        fscanf(stdin, "%i", &j);
    }

    while(i <= j) {
       printf("ASCII value of character %d: %c\n",i,i);
       i++;
}

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```